# Mini slideshow code adaptation

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have this HTML markup:

```
<div id="leftBtn">Left</div>
<div id="rightBtn">Right</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slideshowContainer">
        <div id="slide_1" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_2" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_3" class="slide"></div>
        <div id="slide_4" class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... it corresponds to a super simple slideshow (all credits to jimjimmy1995 for the code). Right now it slides left/right. When clicking the right/left buttons I need the slides to overlap/separate and animate opacity and not slide horizontally. Here's what I've got - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkyZx/). I'm not a jQuery savvy, so I need help in changing the code - feel free to change it.
Thank you.

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding your own slider, you could take a quick look at [nivo-slider](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/), it has a bounce of cool transitions includede right from the get-go, and the implementation is fairly simple.

Good luck :)

Comment: I really want to make it simple - no external libraries. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Something quick & dirty due to shortage of time :) Not sure if i understand your requirements clearly. Make use of jquery .animate API to put some animation.

Note: You need to put check for first & last item in order to cycle through the slides.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkyZx/7/

Change is slideshow function:

```
function slideShow_animate(){
    $('.slide.active').removeClass('active').stop().animate({
        opacity : 0
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).next('.slide').addClass('active').stop().animate({
            opacity : 1
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanx for the feedback. Well, the idea is there, but the behaviour is a bit erratic... white flashes in the middle and colors get a bit mixed up. If you could perfect it it would be great. There's also still the overlaping feature.